# How to include the nested libraries while created the localMaven of a library?

Tags: android, maven, dependencies

I have a library (A) that has further libraries included. Now I want to publish this library A into Localmaven. I use this code to publish it in localmaven.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
publishing {
    publications {
        // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
        release(MavenPublication) {
            // Applies the component for the release build variant.

            // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
            groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
            artifactId = 'final'
            version = '1.3.8'
            artifact(sourceJar)
            artifact bundleReleaseAar
        }

    }
  }
}
```

> I use this in another project. But the problem is when I call the class of A that have classes of sublibraries, application crashed and I see this error.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/studyo/code/CodingViewModel;
```

> **/code is the path of sub library.**